# Stack is totally messed up by trying to produce a buffer overflow

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, stack, buffer-overflow

after hours of debugging without any effort, I hope to find some help here on StackOverflow.

I'm currently on a PTP training and due to the fact that I'm only using Linux, i also want to practice the very firsts Labs on my local machine.

What i have to do is to exploit a very simple Program via buffer overflow. Just the Sources are given:

**goodpwd.cpp:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int bf_overflow(char *str){
       char buffer[10];         //our buffer
       strcpy(buffer,str);      //the vulnerable command
       return 0;
}

int good_password(){            // a function which is never executed
       printf("Valid password supplied\n");
       printf("This is good_password function \n");
       return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
       int password=0; // controls whether password is valid or not
       printf("You are in goodpwd.exe now\n");
       bf_overflow(argv[1]); //call the function and pass user input
       if ( password == 1) {
             good_password(); //this should never happen
 }
         else {
       printf("Invalid Password!!!\n");
 }
       printf("Quitting sample1.exe\n");
       return 0;
}
```

I compiled it to get an executable by using

```bsh
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o goodpwd goodpwd.cpp -ggdb -m32 -lstdc++ -no-pie -O0
```

(I also already tried it without `-no-pie` and `-O0` but I thought maybe the optimization could be the problem..)

I used `gdb` to debug the executable:

```bsh
gdb goodpwd -tui -q
```

After setting a breakpoint to line 6 (the one with the vulnerable strcpy) I executed the following command:

```
(gdb) run AAAAAAAAAAAAAABCDE
```

after pressing `n` to go to the next line, I had a look into the stack:

```
(gdb) x/20x $esp
```

this gave me the following result:

```
0xffffd6f0:     0xffffd748      0x4141a8b0      0x41414141      0x41414141
0xffffd700:     0x41414141      0x45444342      0xffffd700      0x0804923b
0xffffd710:     0xffffd99c      0xf7fe4bd0      0xffffd800      0x08049209
0xffffd720:     0x00000002      0xffffd7f4      0xffffd800      0x00000000
0xffffd730:     0x0804c000      0x00000002      0x08049080      0xffffd760
```

I cannot explain myself why:

- there are two A's at 0xffffd6f4
- there are no A's at 0xffffd6f6
- I got 16 A's starting at 0xffffd6f8
- I got EDCB at 0xffffd704 (because of little endian, thank you @1201ProgramAlarm)
- $bsp is 0xffffd708 and $eip is 0x80491a7 but after doing two more steps (leaving the function) $eip is set to 0x804923e because after all I've learned, I'm pretty sure it should be 0x08049209
- after those two steps I get those error: `main (argc=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x4141a8b0>,
  argv=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x4141a8b4>) at goodpwd.cpp:21`

I'd really appreciate if there's someone who's able to help me.
Struggling in module 3 of 43 is not the best feeling I've ever got :D

Edit:
ASLR should be deactivated:

```bsh
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

Comment: Is [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) a factor here?

Comment: "_Stack is totally messed up by trying to produce a buffer overflow_" - Intriguing title ... Hint: Use `valgrind` - it gives hints as `==868609== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==868609== Invalid read of size 1
==868609==    at 0x483CD34: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:513)
==868609==    by 0x40119F: main (in /home/ted/proj/stackoverflow/title-clang)
==868609==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
`

Comment: You're displaying little endian dwords.

Comment: @tadman: I deactivated it (and updated the post, thank you :) )

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm you're totally right. This explains the "EDCB" Pattern and maybe a little bit the values at 0xffffd6f4. But just a little bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it was a bit too late yesterday. But today I found out, that @1202ProgramAlarm made a very good point.

Because of using a little-endian system, 0xffffd704 was right.
My confusions about 0xffffd6f4 and 0xffffd6f6 have been irrelevant because they not influenced the result.

The value of the old $EIP was still in 0xffffd70e but I never touched it.
I just had to enhance the string in the argument and afterwards I've been able to exploit the vulnerability.
It was a lot of fun. Thanks for the advises.